Adding labels to bars in histogram
This is the code I currently have to generate the following histogram:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    xlabel={Classes},
    ylabel={Frequency},
    width=10cm,
    height=6cm,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={A, B, C, D}, % Add more labels as needed
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    nodes near coords, % Add labels above each bar
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    ]
    
    \addplot[fill=blue!30] coordinates {(1, 15) (2, 12) (3, 8) (4, 10) };

    \addplot[fill=green!30] coordinates {(1, 14) (2, 11) (3, 13) (4, 9) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I want the graphic to look like this instead with the rankings on top of the bars.


Welcome. // For the classes look up symbolic coordinates in the pgfplots manual. // I highly recommend to add the missing lines to your code that make it compile when copied. To see what I mean, copy your posted code into a new file and compile. Thank you

i've fixed the code. not sure how to use symbolic coordinates to add the rankings to the top of the histogram bars tho.

Symbolic coordinates are for the axes, i.e. A, B etc.

i don't want to do anything to the axes. rather than displaying the y value at the top of the histogram bar, i want to display the ranking of the bar with the largest bar for the blue dataset receiving a 1 and the largest bar for the green dataset receiving a 1.

Sorry, then your description was misleading to me. // May be it's a good idea to add a mockup sketch, how you want the diagram to appear in the end?

i've updated the post with the histogram i want

Ok, here is one way to do it. Keys:

add point meta=explicit symbolic to each \addplot
add the values/text you want after each coordinate in [ ]

See pgfplots manual, Ch. 4, p. 114, Version 1.18.1 for details.

%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}    % nicer for development
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    xlabel={Classes},
    ylabel={Frequency},
    width=10cm,
    height=6cm,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={A, B, C, D}, % Add more labels as needed
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    nodes near coords, % Add labels above each bar
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    ]
    
    \addplot[fill=blue!30,
             point meta=explicit symbolic
    ] coordinates {
        (1, 15) [1]
        (2, 12) [2]
        (3, 8)  [4]
        (4, 10) [3]
    };

    \addplot[fill=green!30,
             point meta=explicit symbolic
    ] coordinates {
        (1, 14) [1]
        (2, 11) [3]
        (3, 13) [2]
        (4, 9)  [4]
        };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


thank you so much! this was exactly what i needed

Fine :) as finally I understood ;-)
